# Using f-string with format depending on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

How can I use f-string with logic to format an `int` as a `float`? I would like if `ppl` is `True` to format `num` to 2 decimal places, and if `ppl` is `False` to rformat it as whatever it is.

Something like `string = f'i am {num:.2f if ppl else num}'` but this does not work. The below code demonstrates the behaviour that I want to achieve with a simpler f-string if possible:

```
ppl = True
num = 3
string = f'I am {num:.2f}' if ppl else f'I am {num}'
print(string)
#if ppl False
#=> i am 3
#if ppl True
#=> i am 3.00
```

Comment: I don't understand, it seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: yes...but i would like to short f-string with even clean code

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can nest expressions to evaluate inside expressions in an f-string. This means you can move the ternary right inside your f-string:

```
string = f'I am {num:{".2f" if ppl else ""}}'
```

Note the additional pair of braces needed for nesting.

But I don't think this is *cleaner*. Personally I find it harder to parse what's going on here, as opposed to your clear original version. After all simple is better than complex; flat is better than nested.

Comment: this is disgusting and I like it

Comment: Also the `}}` handling is kind of confusing - usually `}}` means a literal closing brace, but here, `}}` closes two nested replacement fields. Looking at the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), I can see how the parsing rules work out that way, but it's still confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 agreed, if anything I prefer Gamrix' two-step version.

Answer (score 23):

I would recommend that you actually separate the fstring into two lines

```
num_str = f'{num:.2f}' if ppl else f'{num}'
final_str = f'I am {num_str}'
```

That way each line is as simple as it can be.

Comment: Or `form = '.2f' if ppl else ''` and `f'I am {num:{form}}'` on a similar note.

Comment: on the variable names: overriding the `str` default class is not really a good idea