# conditional string in format string (f"{...}")

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, format

As you know over Python 3.6, there is a feature known as [format string literals](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). `str(obj['my_str_index'])` can be either `None` or a string value. I've tried the below one but it doesn't yield `'null'` text if it is `None`.

```
foo = "soner test " \
f"{str(obj['my_str_index']) if str(obj['my_str_index']) is not None else 'null'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using f-string with format depending on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885913/using-f-string-with-format-depending-on-a-condition)

Comment: @JammyDodger it is what actually tried but it doesn't yield my wish. Thanks for your help by the bye.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it this way? it's borderlining abusing the f-string mechanism. I think an explicit if condition will be much more readable

Comment: @DeepSpace highly likely in future nobody needs to touch the code, that is, it can be considered as just two-click script.

Answer (score 4):

`str(None)` is not `None`, but `"None"`. So without that useless and harmful stringification:

```
foo = "soner test " \
f"{str(obj['my_str_index']) if obj['my_str_index'] is not None else 'null'}"
```

EDIT: A more legible way (note that interpolation in an f-string automatically stringifies, so we don't need `str` at all):

```
index = obj['my_str_index']
if index is None:
    index = "none"
foo = f"soner test {index}"
```

EDIT: Another way, with the walrus (limited to 3.8+):

```
foo = f"soner test {'null' if (index := obj['my_str_index']) is None else index}"
```

Comment: Now combine it with Python 3.8's walrus operator so `obj['my_str_index']` is not evaluated twice... 

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh, I was not even close to arguing that this is the best way to do this. :)

Comment: @Armadan if you have better idea, you can post it sir. I can learn ((:

Comment: @DeepSpace if you think there is a better way, I'm very glad to learn, thanks.

Comment: `index = obj['my_str_index'] or "none"`

Comment: @Chris_Rands If this was Ruby, that would have been my answer. In Python, too many things that are not `None` register as falsy.

Answer (score 3):

You can greatly simplify the condition. This will work (in most cases, see the caveat below) and in my opinion a bit more readable

```
foo = f"soner test {obj['my_str_index'] or 'null'}"
```

You don't have to worry about `str(...)` because the interpolation mechanism calls the objects `__str__` method implicitly (if it does not have `__format__`).

**The only caveat with this approach** is that `foo` will contain `null` if `obj['my_str_index']` is **any** of the falsey values (`None`, `0` and any empty sequence).